# Firebase Cloud Messaging topic equivalent in OneSignal

Tags: onesignal

I am looking into migrating my Flutter app push notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging to OneSignal.

My existing Flutter app uses Topics to separate different types of notification that the user would receives. How do I achieve this using OneSignal, does OneSignal supports topic subscription?

Answer (score 2):

Simply send your topic as "tag" for example `await OneSignal.shared.sendTag("topic_name", "1");`, then you can send push notification based on topic_name tag.

For more information see docs:
[Tag Implementation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/data-tag-implementation#sdk-tagging-methods) and [Segmentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/segmentation)